# Spectrum of laser light absorbed and re-emitted by a white object

Tags: reflection, laser, fluorescence

If I shine a red laser onto a white surface, I assume that:

- some of the red light will be nearly instantly reflected,
- some will be absorbed and converted into phonons
- and some will be absorbed and re-emitted.

Is that correct?
I know that my laser has this extremely narrow spectrum:

[image: red laser spectrum]

but **what's the actual spectrum that a white surface emits when I shine it with that laser?**

I would expect some part of the laser light will be re-emitted at lower frequency and another (smaller part) at higher frequency due to Stokes Shift:

[image]

Does it make any difference if the reflector is a white paper, white plastic or white paint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spectrum you get out depends entirely on the physics relevant to the material. What is it made out of? Is it crystalline or disordered? What laser intensities are involved? Different materials have different details which determine the extent to which something like a Stokes shift will occur.

Normally, if you care about emitted light with a similar brightness to the incident light, you’re talking about *linear* scattering. This means that you get out the same color(s) that went in. But there are other cases, too, such as if you have a fluorescent molecule. This could absorb red light and emit infrared light, for example.

If you care about emitted light with *any* intensity, even if it’s orders of magnitude lower than that of the laser, then the zoo of nonlinear effects would be on the table. These include second-harmonic generation (where you’d get out blue light from red) and Raman shifts (where you’d get weak narrow lines to the red and blue of your fundamental line, depending on the material phonon energies).

Comment: Is there a [DIY way](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oulJg0kiiWA) to check the reflected spectrum for various materials with an accuracy of about 1 to 5 nm? I'm mostly interested in a rough estimation of the amount of reflected light that will differ from my laser. PS: great answer, thanks.

Comment: @Smallphysicist unless you have special material, the vast majority of your scattered light will remain red. To a rough approximation, the material is linear, and you get out what you put in.

Comment: @Smallphysicist of course, if you’re looking for fluorescence, by all means, build a spectrometer (or just get a color filter to block the red light and look for anything else that may be there). Some paints and paper will fluoresce.

Comment: When you say it will remain red, do you mean the difference will be less than 1nm? Also, does that type of normal scattering from solid materials have a specific name so that I can read more about it? As for fluorescence (from red laser) I assume it will be less than 10% of the normal reflection, correct?

Comment: @Smallphysicist you are correct! Fluorescence will be relatively small (most likely), and the reflected/scattered light from a linear material will have *exactly* the same spectral components (possibly with different spectral weights, however). Since you have a narrow line laser, you’ll get exactly that same line back out.